# MySQL group having question

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a simple MySQL table like this:

```
create table `users`( 
   `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
   `user` varchar(100) NOT NULL , 
   `registration_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 )
```

and I'm wondering how should I get the `count` of users that have been registered:

- today
- this week
- this month

and is there any way of doing this in a single query ?

Comment: Today and month are easy, but week depends on what you consider to be the start of the week.  Some cultures, it's Sunday - for others it's Monday etc.

Comment: It doesn't really matters, but let's say it starts in Monday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Monday is the start of the week, use:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
             WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(u.registration_date, '%Y-%m-%d') = CURDATE() THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS numToday,
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(u.registration_date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0-WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY)AND CURDATE() THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS numThisWeek,
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN FROM_UNIXTIME(u.registration_date, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m') THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS numThisMonth
  FROM USERS u
```

Though, because of using [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) this won't be able to use an index if one existed on the `registration_date` column.  You could though, if you reversed the logic to apply the [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function to the values for the dates being filtered against.

Comment: May need to add the check to the year as timestamp may span over years.

Comment: @Rasika: Please explain - months don't cross years, and today is too short a scope to worry about.  The week calculation is the only potential I see that would cross years, and this would correctly calculate for the week regardless of crossing a year.

Comment: The month function returns the month part of the date. If there is a timestamp that has the same month, but from a previous year, it will be counted in. So you need to check both month and year to make the logic work properly.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, you are welcome. Your solution is much efficient than mine as it can produce the result in one sweep whereas mine takes 3 sweeps. Well done again.

Answer (score 2):

You could write separate sub queries and join the results for the final answer.

```
SELECT NumToday, NumThisWeek, NumThisMonth 
   FROM
      (SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumToday FROM `users` 
          WHERE date(`registration_date`) = date(now()) 
   JOIN 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumThisWeek FROM `users` 
          WHERE week(`registration_date`) = week(now()) AND year(`registration_date`) = year(now()))
   JOIN
      (SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumThisMonth FROM `users` 
          WHERE month(`registration_date`) = month(now()) AND year(`registration_date`) = year(now()))
```

Comment: Query posted will not be able to use indexes for the `registration_date` column.

Answer (score 1):

if you need last 7 days and last 30 days (not consider the week start or month start)

you can do in one query like this

```
SELECT 
SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(NOW(),registration_date) < 1 , 1 ,0))  AS thisday ,
SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(NOW(),registration_date) < 8  AND DATEDIFF(NOW(),registration_date) > 0 ,1,0))  AS last7day ,
SUM(IF(DATEDIFF(NOW(),registration_date) < 31 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(),registration_date) > 7 ,1,0))  AS last30day 
FROM users 
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),registration_date) < 31
```

Comment: The month calculation is suspect - not all months are 31 days.  The week calculation is rolling - it won't start on Monday/etc.

Comment: i know that, so i wrote that is not month its last 30 days

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `registration_date` >  DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `registration_date` >  DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `registration_date` >  DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

I think this will be correct. haven't tested though.

Comment: actually this is last day, last 7 days, last 30 days

Comment: @teneff You can use the `DAY(CURDATE())` and `DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())` functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by the date (without time) for getting today count,
You can group by datepart of the week or month for getting the relevant query

for example (getting count of today):

Select count(*)
from [table]
group by [date_column]
having [date_column] = getdate()